# How can I convert a reverse IP address to IP?

Tags: shell

I want to convert a list of reverse DNS IP addresses to normal format.

i.e.

Convert `43.201.125.10.in-addr.arpa` to `10.125.201.43`

Is it feasible?

Answer (score 2):

For `IPv4`, with `dig` and `Perl`:

```
$ dig +short PTR 51.28.174.37.in-addr.arpa. |
    perl -F'[.-]' -nE 'say join ".", @F[0..3]'
```

As a string

```
$ echo 51.28.174.37.in-addr.arpa. |
    perl -F'[.-]' -nE 'say join ".", reverse @F[0..3]'
```

```
37.174.28.51
```

Answer (score 1):

```
start cmd:> echo '43.201.125.10.in-addr.arpa' | 
    awk -F. 'NF==6 && $5=="in-addr" && $6=="arpa" { print $4 "." $3"." $2 "." $1; }'
10.125.201.43
```

Answer (score 1):

With plain bash:

```bash
input="43.201.125.10.in-addr.arpa"
IFS='.' read -ra octets <<< "$input"
printf -v ipaddr "%d.%d.%d.%d" "${octets[3]}" "${octets[2]}" "${octets[1]}" "${octets[0]}"
```

then

```bash
$ declare -p ipaddr
declare -- ipaddr="10.125.201.43"
```

Answer (score 1):

It's most definitely feasible. Here's one way

```
echo 43.201.125.10.in-addr.arpa |
    tr . '\n' |
    head -n4 |
    tac |
    xargs |
    tr ' ' .
```

Output

```
10.125.201.43
```

Here's another possibility

```
echo 43.201.125.10.in-addr.arpa |
    ( tr -cd '.0-9' | tr . ' '; echo 'n[.]Pn[.]Pn[.]Pn[]p' ) |
    dc
```

Output

```
10.125.201.43
```

Answer (score 1):

For the text given in your sample an `awk` solution looks as the most easy:

```
awk -F. -v OFS="." '{print $4,$3,$2,$1}'
```

or a `perl` one:

```
perl -F/[.]/ -lsne 'print @F[reverse 0..3]' -- -,=.
```